# iText PDF Approval and Certification Signature

Tags: itext

I am using iText for PDF signing.

My PDF form has 3 signature fields. The first two fields are for approval signatures and the last field is for certification signature. Certification signature is always signed after the approval signatures and Append mode is set to true for all signatures.

My question is after the certification signature is signed (certification level set to CERTIFIED_NO_CHANGES_ALLOWED) the validated approval signatures will become invalidated while the certification signature is validated.

How should I go about fixing this?

Comment: Can you share your signing code? My first thought is that you're not using PdfStamper in append mode, could you also show us how you're constructing PdfStamper?

Answer (score 4):

> Certification signature is always signed after the approval signatures

This is not allowed.

The PDF specification [ISO 32000-1](http://wwwimages.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/devnet/pdf/pdfs/PDF32000_2008.pdf) indicates that

> > The signature dictionary of a certification signature shall be the value of a signature field and shall contain a **ByteRange** entry. It may also be referenced from the **DocMDP** entry in the permissions dictionary (see 12.8.4, “Permissions”). The signature dictionary shall contain a signature reference dictionary (see Table 253) that has a **DocMDP** transform method.
> >
> > *(section 12.8.1  Digital Signatures / General)*
> >
> > The **DocMDP** transform method shall be used to detect modifications relative to a signature field that is signed by the author of a document (the person applying the first signature). A document can contain only one signature field that contains a **DocMDP** transform method; it shall be the first signed field in the document. It enables the author to specify what changes shall be permitted to be made the document and what changes invalidate the author’s signature.
> >
> > *(section 12.8.2.2.1 Digital Signatures / Transform Methods / DocMDP / General)*

I.e. a certification signature has a **DocMDP** transform method and the signature having a **DocMDP** transform method must be the first one signed in the document.

What you try to achieve, though, might be possible otherwise if PDF2 features are ok with you, cf. Bruno's white paper [Digital Signatures for PDF documents](http://itextpdf.com/book/digitalsignatures) section 2.5.5 *Locking fields and documents after signing*:

> > Since PDF 1.5, it’s possible to lock specific fields when signing a document. In PDF 2.0, there will be a new feature that allows you to define the document-level permissions that are already available for certification signatures, but now also for approval signatures.

For details (which go beyond the size of an answer here) read that section...

Comment: I already answered this on the mailing-list although without referring to the specific parts in ISO-32000-1. It's a pity people don't accept answers that tell them they are trying to do something they shouldn't do.